# Как добавить новый пункт в контекстное меню с помощью python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть программа main.exe, написанная с помощью Python(не суть).

Мне нужно что бы при запуске второй программы(например install.exe) в контекстное меню добавлялся пункт с запуском программы main.exe.

То есть, я вызываю на папке контекстное меню и выбираю пункт с этой программой(main.exe) и тогда вызывается эта программа, и в неё передаётся путь к данной папке.

Как такое организовать на Python?